# calculating gaussian curvature on the unit sphere using the Diguet theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I've seen this definition of gaussian curvature on Wikipedia:

$$
K(p)=\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0^+} 12\frac{\pi r^2-A(r)}{\pi r^4}
$$

where $A(r)$ is the geodesic disk of radius $r$

it is my understanding that on the unit sphere the geodesic disk is a spherical cap, meaning

$$
A(r)=2\pi(1-\cos(\frac{r}{\pi}))
$$

but when i tried this case i got a curvature that diverges ($-\infty$) instead of $1$

NOTE:

as i was writing this question i realized that my problem was (probably): what i was thinking of as the radius of the disk is wrong, however if this is indeed the case i am not sure how to arrive at the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should write
$$A(r)=2 \pi\left(1-\cos \left(r\right)\right)$$
Remember that the geodesic distance between the poles is $\pi$ and the surface area of the sphere of radius one is $A(\pi)=4\pi$.
\begin{align}
K(p)&=\lim _{r \rightarrow 0^{+}} 12 \frac{\pi r^{2}-A(r)}{\pi r^{4}}\\
&=\lim _{r \rightarrow 0^{+}} 12 \frac{ r^{2}-2 \left(1-\cos \left(r\right)\right)}{r^{4}}\\
&=\lim _{r \rightarrow 0^{+}} 6 \frac{ r- \sin \left(r\right)}{r^{3}}\\
&=\lim _{r \rightarrow 0^{+}} 2 \frac{ 1- \cos \left(r\right)}{r^{2}}\\
&=\lim _{r \rightarrow 0^{+}}  \frac{ \sin \left(r\right)}{r}=1
\end{align}
The equality's are derived using L'Hôpital's rule.